# Where to report issues about "genkernel all" not selecting reasonable defaults?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, compile, gentoo

`genkernel` states that bugs ought not to be reported against `genkernel` after a failure like

```
drivers/scsi/aha1542.c: In function ‘aha1542_interrupt’:
drivers/scsi/aha1542.c:306:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘isa_virt_to_bus’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   mbo = (scsi2int(mb[mbi].ccbptr) - (isa_virt_to_bus(&ccb[0]))) / sizeof(struct ccb);
   ^
drivers/scsi/aha1542.c: In function ‘aha1542_queuecommand’:
drivers/scsi/aha1542.c:460:4: error: implicit declaration of function ‘isa_page_to_bus’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
    any2scsi(cptr[i].dataptr, isa_page_to_bus(sg_page(sg))
    ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:299: drivers/scsi/aha1542.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:544: drivers/scsi] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

occurs. However as an out-of-the-box user I expect `genkernel` to build a kernel as intuitive as possible, i.e. validate the configuration or reliably pick a working one instead of failing due to a compilation error.

Since it's not a kernel bug, but a kernel source configuration error, there's no place to report this malious behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The text reads

```
* Do NOT report kernel bugs as genkernel bugs unless your bug
* is about the default genkernel configuration...
```

so reporting issues like the one above seems fine.